# How to fade out an element whilst keeping space with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using a piece of jQuery code to hide a table cell whilst keeping the space. It works great but I'm wondering how I can make the element fade out. I tried adding `.fadeOut()` but couldn't get it to work.

```
$(this).closest('td').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Comment: fadeout add the line css display : none

Comment: Animate the opacity down to 0 so it is still there, but invisible. Opacity will not knock the item out like `display: none` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Animate the `opacity` property of the element, this will make sure the element will not be hidden from the dom (keep other items in place), but will make it invisible in a fading way.

```
$(this).closest('td').animate({opacity: 0}, 2000)
```

`.fadeOut()` won't work, simply because it eventually translates to `display: none` which breaks the original document flow.

Example pseudo code:

```js
$('.hello').animate({opacity: 0}, 2000)
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hello">hello</div>
<div class="world">world</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.fadeTo(fast, 0.01)` instead of `$.fadeIn()`.